# mod_rewrite redirect root uri to index.php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

It works fine if i enter url www.domain.com/something and also css and js files ar loaded.
The problem begins if i enter just www.domain.com  (without any params) - browser displays blank. What i need to add so that www.domain.com opens index.php and still all the css files will load?

I tried this

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]
```

but it then none of css files are loaded because I understand that it simply redirects everything to index.php (^$ instead of . also redirects everything to index.php)

I also tried adding at the beginning of index.php so www.domain.com would redirect at the php side

```
header("Location: www.domain.com/begin");
```

but still it is not working because nothing is loaded!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,R=302]
```

Should load the CSS, javascript and images.

Comment: Now browser is saying that This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: I guess, to prevent the loop, `!^/index.html$` should read `!^/index.php$`.