# Simplest task ever with mod_rewrite : redirection to index.php in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just created and uploaded a website using free hosting from byet.com.
  Everything works fine except that typing the mere domain name in the browser does not  redirect the user to my index.php file (an ads page is displayed instead). 
  After googling mod_rewrite and browsing a dozen different pages, I tried adding the following in my .htaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

or

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.php
```

or also (from this Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679303/mod-rewrite-redirect-root-uri-to-index-php) )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,R=302]
```

None of which changed anything, or sometimes caused my index.php page to be inaccessible, with the error message "The script does not redirect properly". 
  Perhaps this behavior is implemented at the level of the httpd.conf file (to which I do not have access), so I will never be able to change that.
  I asked the support center of byte.com about it, but unfortunately the person who answered me did not seem to really understand English or my question.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I think the keyword here is **free hosting**. Perhaps the ad is placed by byet.com, then redirects your users to your site. Doing this, they cover the costs they lose by providing free hosting? As this seems to be a vendor specific question, perhaps it's best to direct your attention to their [community forums](http://byet.net/)? If this happens on all sites, perhaps it's adware?

Comment: Did you delete the default index.**html** that came preinstalled on your hosting space?

Answer (score 0):

If your index.php is under your tld (e.g. http://domain.com/index.php) you can try this;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

Otherwise, if your index.php is in a subfolder (e.g. http://domain.com/my/folder/index.php), you will have to add the path to the RewriteRule;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ /my/folder/index.php [L]
```

If this doesn't work, there is a slight possibility that your host has disabled the mod_rewrite module (although the redirection error message you get suggests otherwise). Have you checked apache's error_log file for relevant messages?

Comment: My file is located at domain.com/htdocs/index.php but typing domain.com/index.php works fine. Where do I find apache’s error-log file ? Via FTP ?

Comment: Then the first solution should work. Your error_log file should be somewhere in the domain's file structure, so, yes, FTP is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php).*$ /index.php [L,NC,R=302]
```